# Не работает выбор специфичных столбцов в SQLAlchemy в scalars

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

При написании запроса со специфичными столбцами в select у меня возращается только первый элемент, который я в нем указал. То есть таком коде

```
query = select(self.model.name, self.model.price).join(CategoryRepository.model).join(
                ImageRepository.model, isouter=True)
```

```
print((await self._session.scalars(query)).all())
```

Возращает `['Туфли', 'Платье', 'Подвеска']` - только названия, хотя sql код генерирует правильный. А при вызове execute все работает правильно

```
print((await self._session.execute(select(self.model.name, self.model.price))).all())
```

Возращает `[('Платье', 350.0199890136719), ('Туфли', 300.04998779296875), ('Подвеска', 99.98999786376953)]`